# What test should I use to identify the significant difference on frequency data that are not normally distributed?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I'm having a problem in identifying which statistical test I should use. My research is about feeding preferences of the Giant panda. I'm observing how frequently the panda eat each type of food in their feeding time. I must find the relationship between the feeding time and the frequency of food consumed but I didn't know which test should I use. If I use ANOVA, my data weren't repeated but I have to use Tukey's test to make a comparison multiple of each of my data. If I use $\chi^2$, the *p*-value showed was for overall data but I need to find a significant difference for each food and time feeding.

Comment: What is the frequency measure exactly? Your last two sentences don't make much sense. This will likely get closed for being unclear and you should probably followup my edits with some of your own. (don't comment but instead edit the question).

Comment: There are ways of accounting for covariates with count data (if that's what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask a clarifying question: when you say "feeding time", do you mean the number of discrete feeds, or the length of time the panda spends feeding?  If its length of time feeding (continuous measure), versus number of feeds as a discrete measure, then **ANOVA** would suit *if your data met assumptions*.  You have said that it isn't normally distributed; how non-normal is it, actually?  To judge this, you need a residual histogram, Normal Q-Q plot, and a test of normality eg. Shapiro-Wilk or Kolgorov-Smirnov (depending on sample size).  If deviations from normal are not too great, and other ANOVA assumptions are satisfied, then you can validly use ANOVA.  Otherwise, a **Generalised Linear Model with Poisson distribution**, graphed with a bar chart.

If on the other hand you a measuring type of food (discrete variable) against how many times the pandas feed, and you treat the counted feeding times like scores, then you would probably have to do **ordinal regression**.  Graph it with a bar chart.